# How to use the awk command in oc exec (openshift command line)

Tags: awk, command-line, rhel, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to get the process names from POD's thorug oc exec command line. I need to grab first filed of each row in the output. I am getting following error. but this `ps -ef|grep NIM| awk '{print $1}'` command works with in the POD.

```
oc exec ngnx-75dbbb4574  --  /bin/bash  -c  'for i in `ps -ef|grep NIM| awk '{print $1}`; do echo $i; done'

}`; do echo $i; done: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
}`; do echo $i; done: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
command terminated with exit code 1
```

Thanks

Comment: You're using RHEL, so you should have `pgrep`, which is included in the `procps` package along with `ps` and `top` and other related utils.  That ancient `ps -ef | grep | awk` pipeline isn't needed (and the grep was never needed anyway, awk alone was enough).  Use `for i in $(pgrep NIM); do echo $i; done` instead.   Or, just  run`pgrep NUM` if all you want to do is output the PIDs.

Comment: ' can't be within '. You could try '\'' for the inner '. – rowboat '   <---- This recomendation is  perfectly working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
oc exec ngnx-75dbbb4574 -- /bin/bash -c "ps ax | awk '/NIM/{print \$1}' | while read i; do echo \$i; done"
```